# How are listeners handled in Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing, events, abstracttablemodel, tablerowsorter

The question is how swing handles listeners. In this example it is the `TableModelListener` which is in focus.

The table model (let us call it `TableModelImpl`) I have is extended from `AbstractTableModel`. Between this table model and the `JTable` I have class called `TableSorter`, which is like a decorator to `TableModelImpl` (and the `TableSorter` also extends `AbstractTableModel`). The `TableSorter` is linked to `TableModelImpl` via association, so what I mean is that `TableSorter` holds a reference to the `TableModelImpl`. Further, the `TableSorter` have member of type `TableModelListener`, which listen to my `TableModelImpl` object. The `JTable` does in turn listen to a `TableSorter`.

So in general it can be said that the `JTable` object listens to `TableSorter`, which listens to my `TableModelImpl`. So the question is: How does this work? Assume for example that I want to call `TableModelStructureChanged()` on my `TableModelImpl` object, will this Event be forwarded to the `JTable` via the `TableSorter` then?

So, some shortened example:

```
public class TableModelImpl extends AbstractTableModel {

private boolean enabled;
public TableModelImpl(//non relevant parameter, linked to data) {
    //Irrelevant code binds model to the data
    this.enabled = false;
}

public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
    this.enabled = enabled;
    fireTableStructureChanged();
}
    // More irrelevant code
}

public class TableSorter extends AbstractTableModel {

private TableModel tableModel;

    private MouseListener mouseListener;
    private TableModelListener tableModelListener;

    public TableSorter() {
        this.mouseListener = new MouseHandler();
        this.tableModelListener = new TableModelHandler();
    }

    public TableSorter(TableModel tableModel) {
        this();
        setTableModel(tableModel); //Adds this.tableModelListener to tableModels listenerList
    }
}
```

So if I do following:

```
TableModelImpl tm = new TableModelImpl();
TableSorter sorter = new TableSorter(tm);
JTable table = new JTable(sorter);
tm.setEnabled(true);
```

Will the JTable be notified?

Comment: Don't describe your code, show it.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Ok I added an example. The real code is quite long, so I tried to include the relevant parts. The TableSorter also have parameters and code related to sorting, which is not related to listeners. Further, there are bindings to the data model, which neither relates to listeners.

Comment: It's hard to say, as we don't have access to your `TableModelHandler` or `setTableModel`.  From the looks of things, `TableSorter` wants to act as a proxy between the `JTable` and `TableModelImp`, so any events triggered by `TableModelImpl` will need to be (possibly modified and) forwarded to whatever listeners are registered with `TableSorter`. `JTable` registers itself as a `TableModeListener` to whatever model you supply it, so assuming you've got the event forwarding set up correctly, then yes, it should work

Comment: @MadProgrammer you are right. The answer turned out to be inside the TableModelHandler class, which contained only the method `tableChanged(e)`. The sole purpose with this class appeared to be forwarding the event from `TableModelImpl` to `JTable`. Apart from this (just for completeness). The method `setTableModel` does what `setModel` does in `JTable`. Sorry about the name. The conclusion is that I should have done more research befroe posting, but I still think it fair to let the users decide whether this question should be closed or not.

Comment: @patrik your code posted for AbstractTableModel is empty for view_to_model events(and vice_versa), the same for Listeners, I'm think that Listeners and sortering/filtering wouldn't be part of models definitions, but "standing data" for sortering/filtering should be part of model, partially is described (helicopter view) in answer by STaefi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swing is a great implementation of most well-known design patterns in java such as `Model-View-Controller`(most of times referred to as **MVC**), `Singleton`, `Factory`, `Observer` and etc.

Many `JComponents` such as `JTable`, `JList` or `JComboBox` are implementing **MVC** pattern.

In many situations when the model is changed, a method like `fireTableDataChanged()` is getting called, which is responsible for iterating over the list of listeners added to the model and call their `tableChanged(TableModelEvent tme)` method. So any other component such as the view will be notified to update it's state due to the changes of the model.

The same is applied when `fireTableStructureChanged()` is called. Since `JTable` is implementing the `TableModelListener` interface and register itself as a listener to it's `TableModel`, it will be notified automatically when you call `fireTableStructureChanged()`.

It's beneficial to see the source code of the `JTable` and `AbstractTableModel` to understand the mechanism of firing and listening to the `TableModelEvent`s.

**[UPDATE]**

There is not a magic way, just method calls. In the `AbstractTableModel` there is a `List<TableModelListener>` called `listenerList`. On the other hand, `JTable` is implementing `TableModelListener` interface. In the constructor of `JTable` class, `JTable` adds itself to the list of listeners in the model. So when anything happens to `TableModel` and its `fireXXX()` methods are getting called, the only magic is iterating over `listenerList` and calling 'tableChanged' method. Since `JTable` is in the list, then 'tableChanged' of `JTable` is called.

Hope this would be helpful.

Comment: I have been looking a bit on these two classes. My guess is that the Event will be forwarded until to the next object until it reaches a JTable, looking at the class `TableSorter` has a nested class `TableModelHandler` Implementing the TableModelListener. This method calls `fireTableChanged`. I can assume this class is responsible for forwarding the event to the `JTable`. I guess that I should have looked a bit closer at the code and not assuming that swing should handle this in some "auto magic way". I feel stupid, thank you for your time and sorry for disturbing.

Comment: @STaefi carrecfully with fireXxx and tableXxxChanged without details , description, because most of them can reseting all custom settings, listener, fitering, sorting..., AbstractTableModel isn't good start_point with comparing with DefaultTableModel

Comment: @mKorbel: as always thanks for good hint, will keep them in mind. Always trying to learn from you - Seniors.